# dedicated button / div for dropping down the select box options

Tags: javascript, select

Is it possible to make the select box drop down by making a dedicated button/div for that?

For example: [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MS5sM/1/) -
I want the select box to drop down when I click on the orange rectangle.

Comment: nothing. I figure it's an onclick event, but I don't know which method/function would do what I want.

Comment: The native `select` element has no programmatic method to automatically open the select list. If you want to trigger this with another element, you're likely better off to create your own version of a drop down.

Comment: @scunliffe yes, thanks for the update sir, i think changing the size of the select box on click of some button would help him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abvious solution would be to call select.click() method, but this won't work.
Here's a library that could do the trick for you: http://code.google.com/p/expandselect/

Comment: with some editing of their source code, this worked out even better for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

i think this one may help for you,

```
<select id="tst" >
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
<option>option</option>
</select>


<input type="button" name="" value="Open" onclick="document.getElementById('tst').size='10';"/>
<input type="button" name="" value="Close" onclick="document.getElementById('tst').size='1';"/>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. .size was the function I was looking for.